# Comparing and forecasting changes in consumption structure

Tags: variance, predictive-models, conditional-probability

My customers are pre-paying services. The payment is not service specific. Customer purchases some capacity and can choose any offered service until his payment is used up or expires. Data could be represented by the example below (each customer has one or more purchases and each purchase gets consumed by services over time). Consumption of one service impacts probability of another one (first some services utilizations are obviously correlated and all share the same "allowance" defined by the purchase volume).

Could you please advice:
- What would be the best statistic comparing differences between current purchase consumption structure and prior purchases consumption structure?
- What would be the best approach forecasting consumption structure of the current purchase based on prior purchases?

---

Data example:
Customer,PurchaseNr,Purchase,Service1,Service2,Service3
1,1,100,8,83,9
1,2,864,608,174,82
1,3,100,6,54,40
2,1,169,110,57,2
2,2,100,17,26,57
2,3,51,22,18,11
3,1,100,39,44,17
3,2,680,463,135,82
4,1,100,30,14,56
5,1,50,39,1,10